# How to make JQuery colorbox properly responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, colorbox

I am using colorbox and bootstrap for creating a popup form.
I have specified the height and width in percentages, While loaded in small mobile screen the form is very small and unusable.
Is there a way to make the popup properly responsive.

[image: Preview in small screen]
[image: Preview in desktop]

Comment: Reduce paddings/margins?

Comment: You mean to overide the bootstrap class properties ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same problem and can not isolate what is reducing the width of the lightbox content.

Answer (score 0):

Use media screen and set `width:90%` or whatever you want for screens less than 768px

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like the following in your CSS:

```
#cboxContent { 
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

You'd also need to add something like the following (using whichever values are appropriate for your interface):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #cboxContent {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
  }
}
```

(I'm doing something similar, but instead of using a percentage width, I set the margins, and change their value to a lower amount for when the screen is narrower.)

And/or you might want to put a `min-width` and `min-height` on `#cboxContent`.